# How to resolve the following "keyserver receive failed" issue on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS while installing MongoDB?

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, terminal, firewall

[Keyserver not available error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC2XL.png)

I am trying to install MongoDB on my system. I try to follow the steps given in the following website - [Click Here](https://hevodata.com/blog/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

I am getting the 'keyserver not available' error as given in the image above due to which I am not able to install MongoDB on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always try to refer the official documentation for these purposes. The article you have linked is an outdated one and it's actually trying to install xenial version on Bionice beaver, which can be done but not recommended.

Use the below offical mongodb documentation to install the MongoDB community version on your Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I already referred to MongoDB official document. However, the problem still persists.

Comment: Did you use the public key provided in the document using the below command `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4`

Comment: Yes. I did. No luck.

Comment: This might help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361642/keyserver-receive-failed-on-every-keyserver-available